# Unable to upgrade ROM [status 7] and Failed to verify whole-life package

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean

i am having an issue upgrading my Serioux S800TAB to android 4.2.2: i get an error: status 7. I have googled the error, and done what the tutorial said, but now i have the error "Failed to verify whole-life package". Any tips on how can i make the ROM work?

Comment: Are you flashing a custom ROM? What's the name of the ROM? What recovery are you using? CWM? TWRP?

Comment: Or are you flashing a stock ROM?

Comment: What is "the tutorial"? What did it say? Can you include the basic steps of what you did?

Comment: I tried CyanogenMod, but i didn't know which one to download, so i downloaded a random one. And the tutorial said to browse to \META-INF\com\google\android\updater-script and remove the first lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just download any ROM and remove the asserts from the manifest. That is a sure fire way to brick your device. You need to find a ROM that is compatible with your device.

The status 7 error is there because you are installing a package that doesn't match the hardware you are trying to install it on. It is a safety measure. The guide for deleting the asserts from the manifest is only meant to allow flashing the file in an older recovery that doesn't recognize the asserts in the manifest. When doing this you have to be **absolutely sure** that you are installing on the proper device.  If you delete the asserts and install on an incompatible device, it may fail still or it could flash, rendering your device useless.

Find a proper ROM for your device and install that. Don't just pick one unless you want to brick your device.

Comment: Error code 7 can also be out of space as well..

Comment: Yes it can and that is good information to know as well. Thanks @t0mm13b. Based on the OP, however, this definitely seems to be related to the assert check in recovery. It is always scary when you read "I didn't know which one to download so I just picked a random one."

Comment: well, i do not know which one could be good for my tablet, i tried searching but i didn't seem to find anything

Comment: It is very possible that there isn't a CM build for your device. In order to get CM on a device, there have to be developers who have the devices who are willing to build it and make it compatible. When you have these obscure inexpensive tablets the odds of finding a CM build for it are pretty low. You may be able to find *some* ROMs for it, but even that is just a guess. ROMs are not universal. You **must** use a ROM designed for your device or you could destroy it. If you can't find any ROMs **for your device**, then you are stuck on stock unless you learn to build ROMs yourself.